# mod_rewrite in a subdirectory: assets not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /focas/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule editoria/([^/]+)/?$ editoria.php?editoria=$1 [QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule tag/([^/]+)/?$ tag.php?tag=$1 [QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

I also include `<base>` meta tag:

```
<base href="http://website.com/focas">
```

But all my assets return 404

Comment: Please provide an example URL of such an asset.

Comment: @colburton This is the correct css path http://boopastudio.com/focas/dist/styles/main.css but the page is looking for http://boopastudio.com/dist/styles/main.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `<base ...` tag to this:

```
<base href="/focas/">
```

and make sure it placed just below your `<head>` tag in the page.